# How to call a servlet from a nav bar href link , and also call a jquery function for slow scroll down on click

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

How to call a servlet from nav bar href link and also same time call a jquery function for slow scroll down

I tried to call the servlet from onclick href link, it is calling but not calling jquery function at the same time

```
   Code for slow scroll down

    $("#apply").click(function() {
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop : $("#applyleave").offset().top
        }, 500);
    });

 Code for calling servlet
function myFunction1() {
        window.location.href = "http://localhost:9091/LeaveManagementProject/ApproveLeave";
    }
```

No error message, just it is calling only one function not the both`enter code here`

Comment: Can you show your `<a>` tag attributes?

Comment: <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#leaveApprove"
      onclick=myFunction1();
       id="apply1">Employee Leave</a></li>

Comment: But you are changing your location with your function? Do you want to scroll to the ID *then* go to your location with myFunction1? If so, you have to [PreventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to delay or bypass the page change.

Comment: Sorry But I didn't understand how can I do both the work at same time onclick it should scroll down using jquery and also call the servlet so that when it reaches to that location it gets the data which is loaded from the servlet

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch data and scroll during the data is fetched, you need to stop the request and do it with XHR.

```
// this makes an asynchronous request to fetch data and executes the callback function
var sendXHRPost = void 0;
{
    sendXHRPost = function (url, params, callback) {
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        http.open('POST', url, true);
        http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        http.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (http.readyState === 4) {
                callback(http.status, http.responseText, clickedElement);
            }
        }
        http.send(params);
    }
}
// your scroll function
var scrollFunction = void 0;
{
    scrollFunction = function (status, response, clickedElement) {
        // update your DOM with reponse here
        // Then scroll
        $("#apply").click(function() {
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop : $(clickedElement.href).offset().top
            }, 500);
        });
    }
}
// Handle the click on your element
var clickFunction = void 0;
{
    clickFunction = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var myURL = "http://localhost:9091/LeaveManagementProject/ApproveLeave";
        sendXHRPost(myURL, null, scrollFunction, e.currentTarget);
    }
}
document.getElementById("apply1").addEventListener("click", clickFunction, false);
```

Hope this helps.